# How to add description to Jenkins job submitted with buildWithParameters?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm triggering a job from a pipeline with the following code:

```
        buildWithParameters(
          jobName: 'other-job',
          propagate: false,
          wait: false,
          parameters: [
            PARAM1: 'param1
          ]
            )
```

Is it possible to set a job description to the newly submitted job using this API?

Comment: What do you mean by job description? The Job description is fixed when you create the job.